# Can't type text in editText dialog using Espresso

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-espresso, android-uiautomator

I am writing an automation test using Espresso an UiAutomator and I am trying to set text inside an editText dialog with the id of 'R.id.message'.
[editText dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgDAN.png)

I've tried everything I saw on the internet and nothing worked for me, except of getting the literal id from the hierarchy view and writing it as is :
`UiAutomatorUtil.findUiObjectById(16908291).setText("1234");`

Obviously this is not a solution, so I'm trying to understand how can I automatically insert text into the given view.

The view doesn't have a text before, so using `withText`/`findUiObjectByText` is not optional.

I've also tried                 `onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.message)).inRoot(isDialog()).perform(typeText("1234"));` and some similar alternative but it always fail to work (there is no error, the test continues as is, but the text won't be typed)

Also, when opening the dialog, the text field is already focused, so a solution of just writing the text without choosing a view before is also optional if possible.

I have no idea what else can I do in order to make it work.
Any help please?

Comment: What was the error when you tried `typeText("1234"`)`?

Comment: There is no error, the gesture just doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

Since the test can continue without error, and you also mentioned that the text view is already focused, then try [typeTextIntoFocusedView](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/espresso/action/ViewActions#typetextintofocusedview) instead:

```
onView(withId(R.id.message)).inRoot(isDialog()).perform(typeTextIntoFocusedView("1234"));
```

`typeText` always perform a simple tap on an editable field to gain focus before it starts sending key events, and sometimes the tap can cause undesirable behavior when the view is already focused.